# How to add oracle hint (use_nl) to a spring boot jpa query

Tags: jpa, hql

I have a hql query

```
select new com.packagename.CountryInfoDto(c.countriesId, c.internationalCode, c.countryName, ot.name) from Country c
inner join OtherTable ot on c.otid = ot.id
    where c.deleted = (:deleted)
    order by c.countryName
```

I create the query like this.

TypedQuery query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString,
BookingInfoDto.class);

Now if I want to hint use_nl(c ot) (use nested loops) how can I add that hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to use a native query.